# Proving $\lfloor na_n \rfloor = 0$ if $a_n > 0$ and $a_n^2<a_n-a_{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> If $a_n > 0$ and $a_n^2<a_n-a_{n+1}$ for any positive integer $n$,
>   prove that:
>
> $$\lfloor na_n \rfloor = 0$$

So $na_n > 0$ and I tried to prove that $a_n < \frac{1}{n}$ with induction.

Base step $n = 1$: $a_1^2 < a_1 - a_2 < a_1 \implies a_1<1=\frac{1}{1}$

Induction step $a_n < \frac{1}{n}$: $a_{n+1}<a_n-a_n^2$ and here I am stuck because I can only prove $a_n-a_n^2 < \frac{1}{4}$ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: The function $f(x) = x-x^2$ is increasing on $[0,\tfrac{1}{2}]$. So if $0 < a_n < \tfrac{1}{n}$, then $f(0) < f(a_n) < f\left(\tfrac{1}{n}\right)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, I got it, but can we show $f$ is increasing on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ without calculus?

Comment: We can write $f(x) = x-x^2 = \tfrac{1}{4}-\left(\tfrac{1}{2}-x\right)^2$. Do you see a way to prove that $f$ is increasing on $[0,\tfrac{1}{2}]$ if we use this form?

Comment: I think, if $x<y$ then $f(y)-f(x)=(\frac{1}{2}-x)^2-(\frac{1}{2}-y)^2=(y-x)(1-x-y)$ and this is positive because $y-x > 0$ and $1>x+y$ because $x<y<\frac{1}{2}$. Is this ok?

Comment: Yeah that works. Actually, you don't need to rewrite $f(x)$ the way I did. Noting that $x < y \le \dfrac{1}{2}$ implies $f(y)-f(x) = (y-y^2)-(x-x^2) = (y-x)(1-x-y) > 0$ is simple enough.

Comment: Ok, thanks again.